# How to send a List<Map<String, String>> as parameter for a GET API

Tags: api, rest

I have a requirement to pass List<Map<String, String>> as a parameter for REST GET API.
I need help to know how this can be passed from Postman or similar tool.

I tried to set it as a BODY for a GET API, it is giving me errors.

**400.** That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  That’s all we know.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to design your own API to support this? or are you trying to use an API that you don't control?

Comment: My requirement is to pass  List of Objects and  each object has set of optional values. Based on the list of objects, my service needs to do business logic to fetch details.  This is a new service I am intending to create to be called from Front end.

Answer (score 0):

**You can very well !**

**I tried and this worked for me**

1. Create a model class which has variable of type `List<Map<String, String>> myList;`
2. Define a controller similar to below

   @PostMapping("/addList")

   ```
    public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, String>>> passList(@RequestBody ListModel listModel) {
        System.out.println("List mapped " + listModel);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
   ```
3. Create a request from Postman or any tool like this

   {
   "myList": [
   {
   "one": "1",
   "two": "2"
   }
   ]
   }
4. Response I got

   List mapped ListModel [myList=[{one=1, two=2}]]
5. Make sure you map correct variable name ( for e.g. I have defined myList, so that must be passed so it gets properly mapped in Controller class ) also assuming toString, GetterSetters , and your familiarity with few basic REST annotations related to Spring/SpringBoot :)

Comment: Thanks Harsh,  This works for me too  as a POST method, but the intended operation should be a GET method. Functionality of this API is GET (and with a BODY as the data cant be passed as query params) which will run some queries behind to fetch data and return).  I believe we should not use POST as it is not creating any new resource.

Comment: Assuming the List<Map<>> model is already created, you can return it from your GET API call as well :) Do upvote my previous answer if that works for you :p